# Select from one table if no records found in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
t1
------------
id
user


t2
------------
user_id
item
```

I need to select from t1 if no matching records found in t2

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.user_id)
WHERE ???
```

Kinda stuck...

Comment: Please specify more like, what you want to select if matching what data in the table.

Comment: What about if there is a match in t2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON  t1.id = t2.user_id 
WHERE t2.user_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE user_id = t1.id
);
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1195d/1/0)**.